# jquery callback function is triggers the last line before looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-callback

I'm trying to create a callback function which loops my word animation. I created a jquery function which fades in and out each word with a certain color. I would like this small animation to loop correctly. The issue is that once I callback the function it does not start from the beginning, it repeats again the last code. So this in this example, you will see the key word mult-purpose two times.

Click [here](http://rosasusaeta.com/cepods/) to see a temporal sample of what I mean.

This is my jquery code:

```
function wordfade(){
        $('#msg').fadeIn(2000, function() {
            $('#msg').html("Sustainable").css("color", "#3AE44E").delay(800).fadeOut(2000, function() {
                $('#msg').fadeIn(2000).html("Eye Catching").css("color", "#F18D0B").delay(800).fadeOut(2000, function(){
                    $('#msg').fadeIn(2000).html("Modern Design").css("color", "#0B8DF1").delay(800).fadeOut(2000, function(){
                        $('#msg').fadeIn(2000).html("Energy Efficient").css("color", "#AD0BF1").delay(800).fadeOut(2000, function(){
                            $('#msg').fadeIn(2000).html("Restaurant").css("color", "#F10B0B").delay(800).fadeOut(2000, function(){
                                $('#msg').fadeIn(2000).html("Retail & Pop-Up").css("color", "#C39813").delay(800).fadeOut(2000, function(){
                                    $('#msg').fadeIn(2000).html("Event Space").css("color", "#4FB186").delay(800).fadeOut(2000, function(){
                                        $('#msg').fadeIn(2000).html("Bar & Lounge").css("color", "#F10BA3").delay(800).fadeOut(2000, function(){
                                            $('#msg').fadeIn(2000).html("Residential").css("color", "#C7C7C7").delay(800).fadeOut(2000, function(){
                                                $('#msg').fadeIn(2000).html("Hotel & Lodging").css("color", "#565457").delay(800).fadeOut(2000, function(){
                                                    $('#msg').fadeIn(2000).html("Multi-Purpose").css("color", "#F1880B").delay(800).fadeOut(2000, wordfade);
                                                })
                                            })
                                        })
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        });
    }
    wordfade();
```

Comment: This somehow reminded me of ASCII art.. :-)

Comment: I tried to enter `OMG` but my comment was too short.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2WG4J/ <- copied your exact code into a fiddle, shortened the times and it seems to work just fine

Comment: @Fenixp So why is it not working as in your fiddle?

Comment: @Andy I'm not a big expert with jquery, is there another method so I don't have codes which are referring to the term, OMG?

Comment: @Fenixp - That fiddle has the same problem, "Multi-purpose" appears twice in a row, it's just less noticeable because it happens so fast.

Comment: Normally with intense nesting like that I would try to find an alternative solution, perhaps using a `setTimeout` to loop over an object that holds the word and style information. YMMV tho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first line of your function does a `.fadeIn()` and waits until that's finished before setting the `.html()` on the next line. So the second time it fades in while the html content is still the final word. Just combine the first two lines to look more like the other lines and it will work:

```
function wordfade() {
    $('#msg').fadeIn(2000).html("Sustainable").css("color", "#3AE44E").delay(800).fadeOut(2000, function () {
        $('#msg').fadeIn(2000).html("Eye Catching").css("color", "#F18D0B").delay(800).fadeOut(2000, function () {
         // etc.
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PNDg4/

And then consider rewriting the whole thing to avoid so many nested callbacks:

```
var words = [
    { word : "Sustainable", color : "#3AE44E" },
    { word : "Eye Catching", color : "#F18D0B" },
    { word : "Modern Design", color : "#0B8DF1" },
    { word : "Energy Efficient", color : "#AD0BF1" },
    /* etc */],
    current = -1;

function wordfade() {
    current = (current + 1) % words.length;
    $("#msg").html(words[current].word)
             .css("color", words[current].color)
             .fadeIn(2000)
             .delay(800)
             .fadeOut(2000, wordfade);
}
wordfade();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PNDg4/1/

Comment: I just used your code and it works perfectly. It's obviously much more clear than mine. I want to understand it as it could be useful to learn. The part of the code I do not understand is current and its number. SO I do not get current=-1; and current = (current + 1) % words.length; Could you kindly explain this?

Comment: Pipped at the post :)

Comment: Daniel, array indices (in JS) start at 0 for the first element, and go to the array length minus one for the last element. So I initialise the _current_ variable to -1 and then on the first line of the function I increment it. _%_ is the modulo operator: it returns the remainder when dividing its first operand by the second, so eventually when _current_ is incremented all the way up to the length of the array it gets set back to zero so as to keep looping through the array without ever running past the end.

Answer (score 3):

I was feeling generous...

```
var index = 0;
var words = [
    { text: "Sustainable", color: "#3AE44E" },
    { text: "Eye Catching", color: "#F18D0B" },
    { text: "Modern Design", color: "#0B8DF1" },
    { text: "Energy Efficient", color: "#AD0BF1" },
    { text: "Restaurant", color:  "#F10B0B" },
    { text: "Retail & Pop-Up", color:  "#C39813" },
    { text: "Event Space", color:  "#4FB186" },
    { text: "Bar & Lounge", color:  "#F10BA3" },
    { text: "Residential", color:  "#C7C7C7" },
    { text: "Hotel & Lodging", color:  "#565457" },
    { text: "Multi-Purpose", color:  "#F1880B" }];

function wordfade() {
    $("#msg")
        .html(words[index].text)
        .css("color", words[index].color)
        .fadeIn(2000).delay(800).fadeOut(2000, function() {
            index = ++index % words.length;
            wordfade();
        });
}

wordfade();
```

**[Working jsFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/2WG4J/2/)**

Comment: +1 just to take you to 7777 rep. (And because you might've had the accepted answer if you'd typed a little faster - I assume we were writing our answers simultaneously.)

Answer (score 1):

It's because it starts with $('#msg').fadeIn(2000, function(), so it fades in the last content. you should combine $('#msg').fadeIn(2000, function()  with the second row (havent tested it)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the start of your function fading in the contents of #msg

The last action of the function is to set #msg to "Multi-Purpose" and the start of your function is to fade in the contents.  Just have the start of your function set #msg and then fade in.

Comment: I just forked your fiddle to show what i'm talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/5ubj4/1/